# Need to access the name of field from map of Sobject

Tags: apex-code, visualforce, apex, salesforce-service-cloud, salesforce-chatter

I have a map of `sobject`s like this:

```
Map<String,list<sobject>> recordIdsMap = new Map<String,list<sobject>>();
```

Now my requirement is to iterate over this map, access the field and assign some value to it.

Code that I am currently trying for this:

```
for(Sobject target: recordIdsMap.values()){

  target.BR_District__c = recorddestinationId;
  obj.add(target);

}
```

But this isn't able to access the field name `BR_District__c` because it can't identify the object type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use [put(fieldName, value)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.200.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#apex_System_SObject_put) method on your sObject (*target* in your case).

Should be smth like

```
for(Sobject target : recordIdsMap.values()) {    
  target.put('BR_District__c', recorddestinationId);
  obj.add(target);    
}
```